# MYSQL Left Join how do I select NULL values?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

This is a follow up question to my last question about table joins in MySQL

I need to be able to select the NULL values from the left joined table.

Here's my join:

```
table1.id | table1.name | table2.id | table2.surname
        1 |        John |         1 |            Doe
        2 |     Michael |         2 |       Anderson
        3 |        Anna |      NULL |           NULL
        4 |         Sue |      NULL |           NULL
```

I would want to `select WHERE table2.surname = NULL`, but a query like this doesn't work:

```
SELECT table1.*,table2.*
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
    ON table1.id=table2.id
WHERE table2.surname=NULL
```

I can somewhat understand  the logic behind it not giving me any results, but there must be a way to grab them results?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 46):

To compare `NULL` values you have to use the `IS NULL` predicate, like this:

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.*
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id
WHERE table2.surname IS NULL
```

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but you have to use a `WHERE` clause, not the `AND` clause in the join, to get back meaningful values. That was tripping me up.

Answer (score 13):

You have to use `IS NULL` instead of `= NULL`:

```
WHERE table2.surname IS NULL
```

The reason why you can't simply do `= NULL` is because `NULL` is essentially an "unknown" and can't ***equal*** or ***not equal*** to anything (not even itself), so trying to compare it to something as if it were supposed to be an exact match would simply return `NULL` instead of an expected boolean `0` or `1`, and that's exactly why your query was returning an empty result.

There's a clear difference between *"is unknown"* and *"equals unknown"*. You can surely test if something **is** unknown or **is not** unknown, but you can't test if something ***"equals"*** unknown because unknown is *unknown*, and it wouldn't make sense.

Also, since you're using MySQL, another option would be to use `table2.surname <=> NULL`, where `<=>` is a MySQL-specific NULL-Safe comparison operator, but try not to use that and just stick with the standard SQL way (`IS NULL` / `IS NOT NULL`)

Answer (score 4):

try with:

```
SELECT table1.*,table2.* 
FROM table1 
  LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id 
WHERE table2.surname IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [MySQL specification](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html) you should use "IS NULL" instead of "= NULL".
It says that "(NULL = NULL) equals to NULL". But NULL equals False while it used as Boolean.