# r - dbWriteTable or a MySQL Delete query?

Tags: mysql, r, database, dataframe

I can't seem to find the answer to this anywhere.  I am reading a csv into a data frame using the read.csv function.  Then I am writing the data frame contents to a mysql table using dbWriteTable.  This works great for the initial run to create the table, but I each run after this needs to do either an insert or an update depending on whether the record already exists in the table.

The 1st column in the data frame is the primary key, and the other records contain data that might change every time I pull a new copy of the csv.  Each time I pull the  CSV, if the primary key already exists, I want it to update that record with the new data, and if the primary key does not exist(eg: a new key since the last run), I want it to just insert the record into the table.

This is my current dbWriteTable.  This creates the table just fine the 1st time it's run, and also inserts a "Timestamp" column into the table that is set to "on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" so that I know when each record was last updated.

```
dbWriteTable(mydb, value=csvData, name=Table, row.names=FALSE, field.types=list(PrimaryKey="VARCHAR(10)",Column2="VARCHAR(255)",Column3="VARCHAR(255)",Timestamp="TIMESTAMP"), append=TRUE)
```

Now the next time I run this, I simply want it to update any PrimaryKeys that are already in the table, and add any new ones.  I also don't want to lose any records in the event a PrimaryKey disappears from the CSV source.

Is it possible to do this kind of  update using dbWriteTable, or some other R function?

If that's not possible, is it possible to just run a mysql query that would delete any duplicate PrimaryKey records and keep just the 1 record with the most current timestamp?  So I would run a dbWriteTable to append the new data, and then run a MySQL query to prune out the older records.

Obviously I couldn't define that 1st column as an actual PrimaryKey in the DB as my append/delete solution wouldn't work due to duplicate keys, and that's fine, I can always add an auto increment integer column to the table for the "real" primary key if needed.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a temp table (an exact replica of final table but with less records) and then run an `INSERT` and `UPDATE` query into final table which will handle both cases without overlap (plus primary keys are constraints and queries will error out if attempts are made to duplicate any):

1. records to append if not exists - using the [LEFT JOIN NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500150/mysql-left-join-how-do-i-select-null-values) query
2. records to update if does exist. - using the [UPDATE INNER JOIN](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/) query

Concerning the former there is a regular debate among SQL coders if [LEFT JOIN NULL or NOT IN or NOT EXISTS](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) is the optimal solution which of course "depends". Left Join used here does avoid subqueries. But consider those avenues if needed.

```
# DELETE LAST SET OF TEMP DATA
dbSendQuery(mydb, "DELETE FROM tempTable")

# APPEND R DATA FRAME TO TEMP DATA
dbWriteTable(mydb, value=csvData, name=tempTable, row.names=FALSE,
             field.types=list(PrimaryKey="VARCHAR(10)", Column2="VARCHAR(255)", 
                              Column3="VARCHAR(255)", Timestamp="TIMESTAMP"), 
                              append=TRUE, overwrite=FALSE)

# LEFT JOIN ... NULL QUERY TO APPEND NEW RECORDS NOT IN TABLE
dbSendQuery(mydb, "INSERT INTO finalTable (Column1, Column2, Column3, Timestamp)
             SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, Timestamp 
             FROM tempTable f
             LEFT JOIN finalTable t  
             ON f.PrimaryKey = t.PrimaryKey
             WHERE f.PrimaryKey IS NULL;")

# UPDATE INNER JOIN QUERY TO UPDATE MATCHING RECORDS
dbSendQuery(mydb, "UPDATE finalTable f
             INNER JOIN tempTable t  
             ON f.PrimaryKey = t.PrimaryKey
             SET f.Column1 = t.Column1,
                 f.Column2 = t.Column2,
                 f.Column3 = t.Column3,
                 f.Timestamp = t.Timestamp;")
```

For the most part, queries above will be compliant in most SQL backends should you ever need to change databases. Some RDMS do not support `UPDATE INNER JOIN` but equivalent alternatives are available. Finally, the beauty of this route is all processing is handled in the SQL engine and not in R.

Comment: I like this, but I think you have the logic backwards on the insert query.  Shouldn't it be dbSendQuery("INSERT INTO finalTable
             SELECT t.* FROM tempTable t
             LEFT JOIN finalTable f  
             ON f.PrimaryKey = t.PrimaryKey
             WHERE f.PrimaryKey IS NULL;")

Comment: Thank you!  This works much better.  I do like moving all the actual processing to the database and out of r.  Works like a charm!

Comment: Great! You'd be surprised how many R even Python programmers reshape/transpose/pivot/conditionally group and aggregate dataframes all in memory when a simple, maintainable query run in an SQL engine that can handle millions of indexed records can be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to do an upsert.

I'm kind of rusty with MySQL but the general idea is that you need to have a staging table to upload the new CSV, and then in the database itself do the insert/update.

For that you need to use dbSendQuery with INSERT ON DUPLICATE UPDATE.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: This works, but I would have to do all those "upserts" in R which is very slow on a large data set(about 10k records).  I'd have to loop through each record and run the INSERT query which takes a really long time.  The dbWriteTable command can load this dataframe in a matter of seconds.  While this is a valid solution, it's not the most efficient solution for my problem.

Comment: That is not what I am recommending.
You should load the new table into MySQL with a dbWriteTable, and then do the upsert on the DB side by using a dbSendQuery to send a SQL query to MySQL to do the upsert.