# Typeorm - using subqueries

Tags: mysql, typeorm

I have got 3 entities in my database, we can imagine these 3(I kept only important columns)

```
User     

     @PrimaryColumn()
    nick: string

    @OneToMany(type => Connection, connection => connection.user)
    connections:Connection[] 

Connection 

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @ManyToOne(type => User,user => user.connections) 
    user: User;

    @ManyToOne(type => Stream) 
    stream: Stream;

Stream
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;
```

I think that I have some skills with building Queries in typeorm, but I am stucked right now on using subquery.

**What I want to do?**
Join all User entites on part of Connection entites(Select few of Connection entities as subquery => make leftJoin User-subquery => filter results to get connections which didnt find right(Connection) side so Connection ID is NULL ).

**What I tried?**

```
let query = await connectionRepository
.createQueryBuilder('connection')
.subQuery()
.where("connection.id = :id",{id:1})
.select(['connection.id','connection.user AS nick'])
.getQuery();

const result = await userRepository.createQueryBuilder("user")
                .leftJoinAndSelect("user.permissions", '(' + query + ')')
                .where("user.nick = :nick")
                .andWhere(`(${query}).id is null`)
                .getMany();
```

I also tried to use subquery without .getQuery() but It didnt work anyway, I think that I can write Ok subquery, but then I have problem to use it in the second query(with subquery attributes etc.)
I have also seen some examples with lambda functions, but lambda was always on first position in the leftJoin.

Thank you for your answer:)

Comment: Please describe what you would like to achieve in a "human language" rather than in SQL. What kind data would you like to get?

Comment: I would like to get all Users which dont have Connection to specific Stream.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like that:

```
const result = await userRepository.query(`
      SELECT user.* FROM user
      LEFT JOIN connection connection ON user.id = connection.user_id
      WHERE connection.user_id IS NULL
      AND connection.id = ?;
    `, [id])
```

Related question: [MYSQL Left Join how do I select NULL values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500150/mysql-left-join-how-do-i-select-null-values)

Comment: No, you cant do it like that, because where + andWhere is executed after command, so you dont have any rows with connection.user_id IS NULL(I tried it with testing data and I got [], but I should get 3 users). Only possible way how to do this is with subquery, because you need to execute join only on part of Connection entities.

Comment: Can you use raw query?

Comment: SELECT * FROM User LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM Connection WHERE stream = 5) AS Connection ON User.nick = Connection.user WHERE Connection.id IS NULL;                     I dont know how Postgres exactly stores, ManyToOne and OneToMany, but I have created trial Postgres models and this query worked as I want.

Comment: I used the query I wrote in the answer in my project, but as raw SQL and it worked. I guess that it does not work with the generated query because of the FK or something like that. Sometimes raw is the solution.

Comment: Tbh I didnt know about option of raw query :D I tried it out and its working right now, thank you for your tip and help :)